# How to increase Reading pane Font size in Outlook 2013?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am using Outlook 2013 on a Terminal server (Windows server 2012).

I have problem with Reading Pane font size, it looks like a micro font. I can't even look at it.

Increasing the size of the text in the Reading Pane (zooming in) only works on the email I'm currently looking at.

When I click on another email, the body text will return to the default font size, every time I need to zoom in for every email I have.

Is there any work around to increase font size permanently? 
Please Suggest. . . .

Comment: A quick Google found this: [Enlarge font in the Reading Pane](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/67)

Comment: It is referring to zoom the reading pane, i did that but  only works on the email i'm currently looking at its not permanent. .  :/

Comment: There are multiple solutions listed there. Including increasing the system DPI.  Did you try that?  Are all emails small, or just specific ones?  Which format are the tiny-looking ones in (plain-text, HTML, RTF?)

Comment: As im using Terminal server i cannot go throw system DPI ,
Sorry for being unclear, it is in plain text .

Comment: This might be almost the same what @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 suggested, but are these instructions helpful to you: https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=32629#font-size-reading-pane ? If not, could you do some sort of VBA hack to accomplish the font size increase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option in Outlook to permanently change the zoom level in the reading pane.
For a permanent change, I see two solutions.

**Solution 1 : VBA macro**

Use the VBA macro below, detailed in the article
[How to Always Open Your Email in a Custom Zoom Level with Outlook VBA](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/always-open-email-custom-zoom-level-outlook-vba/).

```
Private WithEvents objInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Private WithEvents objMail As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set objInspectors = Outlook.Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub objInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If TypeOf Inspector.CurrentItem Is MailItem Then
       Set objMail = Inspector.CurrentItem
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub objMail_Open(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim objMailDocument As Word.Document

    'When opening an email which is not a new mail
    If Len(Trim(objMail.Subject)) <> 0 Then
       Set objMailDocument = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
       'Change "150" as per your desired zoom level
       objMailDocument.Windows(1).Panes(1).View.Zoom.Percentage = 150
    End If
End Sub
```

Instructions :

- Start Outlook
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
- Access the `ThisOutlookSession` project on the left side and double-click
- Copy the above VBA code into this project window
- Digitally sign this code by the “Tools” button in the toolbar and
  choosing “Digital Signature…” from the drop-down list.
- In the popup dialog box, enable a digital certificate
- Exit the “Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications” window and restart Outlook
  to activate the new VBA project
- From now on, every time when you open an email which is not a fresh new mail, the email will display in your custom zoom level

[image]

**Solution 2 : Zoom Email Windows (trialware, $9.95)**

Another option is to get the trialware
[Zoom Email Windows](http://www.sperrysoftware.com/Email-Tools/product/zoom-email-windows/) ($9.95) :

> The Zoom Email Windows tool for Outlook automatically zooms all Outlook reading pane windows. It zooms every Outlook window to your specified zoom factor. It’s perfect for being able to instantly and clearly see the email and other Outlook windows.

Comment: If Ranveer is using outlook on terminal server then they probably can't install software

Comment: @StevenPenny : Any comments?

Comment: @harrymc doesnt work with 2013

Comment: @StevenPenny: Surprising. You mean the VBA doesn't work? Do you see anything happening? I don't have 2013 so cannot test.

Comment: all the steps looks ok - but when i restart outlook it just does nothing - i did get a warning about macros but i just hit enable so it should work - i didnt do the steps with the certificate but i can if its absolutely necessary

Comment: @StevenPenny: It might be necessary - Microsoft changes security rules all the time so I can't be sure of what will work in your environment.